# create and persist settings value at runtime

Tags: c#, runtime, persist

I use C# 4.0, VS2010, Winforms.
I have a DevExpress [SplitContainerControl](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsSplitContainerControltopic) on a base form, that I want to persist it's [SplitterPosition](http://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsSplitContainerControl_SplitterPositiontopic.aspx) (int) in derived forms in user config file at runtime.
I use the following code to get/generate the settings property name:

```
string _splitterSettingsName;
public string SplitterSettingsName {
    get {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_splitterSettingsName))
            _splitterSettingsName = GetType().Name + "splitterSettings";
        return _splitterSettingsName;
    }
    set { _splitterSettingsName = value; }
}
```

I need a code to persist the splitter position (int value).
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in settings. In visual studio open MyProject -> Properties -> Settings.Settings. Create a user scope (so it can be edited at run time) setting.
You can then access that setting in code as a property:

```
Properties.Default.Settings.MySettingName = _splitterPosition;
```

And vice versa.

**Update**

As mentioned in my comment, I'd advise against dynamic names. However, I'll give you an idea how you might implement dynamicly named settings. You will want to create a class inheriting from `System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase`, and implement a method taking a string parameter that it then passes to the internal indexer. Something like:

```
public sealed class MySettings : ApplicationSettingsBase
{
    public int GetSplitterPos(string splitterName)
    {
        return ((int)(this[splitterName]));
    }
    public void SetSplitterPos(string splitterName, int pos)
    {
        this[splitterName] = pos;
    }
}
```

Comment: the splitter is in the base form, the settings property name is dynamically generated the first time the derived form is loaded.

Comment: the persisting code should go into the base form, the settings property name is generated dynamically in the derived form.

Comment: Why would you dynamically generate a settings name at all?
Especially for something like a splitter control. I would strongly recommend you do it manually, dynamically generating names can get you in a mess.

Comment: BaseForm has all the necessary code to generate (if doesn't exist already) the splitter settings property name, when I create the derived form I don't care about persisting, because the BaseForm takes care about it.